# MNIST-like issue. Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, mnist

This should be easy for some, but I'm a bit new to Tensorflow and all my research has brought me to multi-thousand line gits and I'm just curious if there is a simpler alternative for a beginner.  I had an idea which inputs a 200x260 color image and outputs a one-hot vector between 1-10.  I realized it is very similar to MNIST, but Tensorflow does not have any documentation on how the mnist library turns its images into a usable form.  Does anybody have any ideas to turn a folder of about 200 images (yes, I know, small) into a usable form?  I already have my one-hot vectors.  Also, I set my placeholder shape as `tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, 200, 260, 3])`  Would that work?  I would really prefer to maintain color as well.  Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can import all of your images using `imread` from `skimage`

For example:

```
my_image = skimage.io.imread('./path/myimage.png')
```

Then if all of them are in the size you desired (200x260) then you can normalize them by dividing all of them by 255 (normalized to a value between 0 and 1). If not, you can use `resize` from `skimage`, this will automatically resize and normalize the images for you.

For example

```
my_image = skimage.transform.resize(my_image, (200, 260))
```

To visualize it, you can use `imshow` from `matplotlib.pyplot` to plot the image.

For the convenient `next_batch` function that grabs next batch built in in `Tensorflow`, you can use the following code

```
i = 0
def next_batch(batch_size):
    x = training_images[i:i + batch_size]
    y = training_labels[i:i + batch_size]
    i = (i + batch_size) % len(training_images)
    return x, y
```

Then you can create your CNN and train the images. The placeholder you created for `X` looks right.

Comment: Wow.  That was the fastest response I've ever gotten.  Just what I was looking for, too.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: No problemo, I have added some example codes as well

Comment: Even better. :)

Comment: I started a little test with skimage, which I downloaded using pip (and then the website to try to fix the error), but unfortunately I got the error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imgtest.py", line 4, in <module>
    image = skimage.io.imread('./shoes/1.jpg')
AttributeError: module 'skimage' has no attribute 'io'`  Any ideas?

Comment: Seems I was able to get something similar with scipy.misc.  All good!

Comment: Yea there are a lot of way to load images, but skimage is my favorite. If you are getting that error I think you did something wrong while installing. [Here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html?highlight=imread#skimage.io.imread) is the documentation for imread.

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled with that in the beginning, but the best way that I know to get data into tensorflow would be to convert your images into the tfRecord format. Especially if you have a large dataset that doesn't fit into RAM. That way tensorflow can load in your data as needed (You need to provide input functions to convert your files back).
Although this might not be/certainly isnt the easiest way it would probably be the best in the long run in case you want to add more images.

To easiest way would just be to load your images using pillow or any other image library (I'm assuming your using tensorflow with python) and hand them over to tensorflow when running your session.

Comment: That's interesting.  I'll definitely try it out because this experiment was successful.  I think I'll look into larger datasets so this would definitely help.  Thanks!